# Crawling through a YouTube channel via the YouTube API

Tags: python, youtube

This code uses the YouTube API for crawling through a YouTube channel, parsing responses and syncing the channel videos with a local directory.

Can this be optimised or improved?

```
import subprocess
import os
import urllib.request as urlreq
import urllib.parse as urlparse
import simplejson as json

playlistIds = []
titles = []

def getPlaylistId():
    data = {}
    data['maxResults'] = '50'
    data['channelId'] = 'UCtESv1e7ntJaLJYKIO1FoYw' # Put the channelId of channel you want to Sync to.
    data['part'] = 'snippet'
    data['key'] =   'AIzaSyAngcF6oKnyEbhk3KyL9Wz1OhSi28JjbzE'
    requestValues = urlparse.urlencode(data)
    request = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?" + requestValues
    string = urlreq.urlopen(request).read().decode('utf-8')
    items = json.loads(string)['items']

    for item in items:
        playlistIds.append(item['id'])
        titles.append(item['snippet']['title'])

def download():
    for ids,title in zip(playlistIds,titles):
            url = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=" + ids
            if not os.path.exists(title):
                os.makedirs(title)
            os.chdir("./" + title)
            url_down = "youtube-dl -o '%(title)s' " + url
            subprocess.call(url_down, shell=True)
            os.chdir("..")

getPlaylistId()
download()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global variables are almost never needed.  You should pass `playlistIds` as a parameter.  Well, actually, just don't make `getPlaylistId()` modify the list; make it return the list.  Even better, make it a generator function that yields each id and title.  That's better because you aren't storing the id's and titles in memory.

Your naming is not in accordance with [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide:

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards compatibility.

and for [Method Names and Instance Variables](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables):

> Use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

You seem to have some *magic values* such as `'50'`, `'UCtESv1e7ntJaLJYKIO1FoYw'`, etc.  How did you come up with those values?  I would suggest making constants at the beginning of the file for your defaults.  Then, use [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) or, if you want to be fancier, [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to get the values from the user.

Instead of creating a dictionary (`data`) and then setting all of the values, why not just create a dictionary with the right values in the first place?  That is, `data = {'maxResults': '50', 'channelId': 'UctESv1e7ntJaLJYKIO1FoYw', ...}`

Instead of defining `items` just to iterate, why not `for item in json.loads(string)['items']:`?

Your indentation in `download()` is odd.  You use four spaces everywhere else, but here you use eight.  Be consistent at the least.

> ```
> os.chdir("./" + title)
> ```

Don't make it a habit to put the dots and the slashes in yourself.  Use `os.path.join(os.curdir, title)`.  `os.chdir("..")` also would change to `os.chdir(os.pardir)`.

Let's say I want to use your program in mine, but I have a different list of id's to get and a different list of titles.  This is my program:

```
from downloader import download

def get_ids_and_titles():
    ...
download(get_ids_and_titles())
```

After the first line, your program just did its thing.  It downloaded everything.  I didn't want to run your program; I wanted to use one of its functions.  You can find out if your program is being run as a module or as a program like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    download(getPlaylistId())
```

If your program is run as a program, `__name__` is `__main__`, but if it is a module, it will be the name of the module.